# Ребят помогите с выводом данных из бд

Tags: php, mysql

Меня интересует запрос-.$row["targeting"]. который выводит значение. Надо сделать так чтобы вывод .$row["targeting"]. не показывал значение 0, а только больше 0. Вроде правильно выразился.

```html
<p class="style-price-grid"><strong>'.$row["targeting"].''.$row["darom"].''.$row["obmen"].'</strong></p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне надо чтобы просто 0 пропали и все, а остальное все осталось)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как не выводить цифру 0 из БД](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560901/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94)

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в цикл перед выводом/запоминанием информации:

```
 if($row["targeting"] == 0) continue;
```

Comment: щяс все товары пропали с значением 0, за то один товар остался с ценой 2500, немного не то)

Comment: а что нужно с товарами с ценой о делать?

Comment: с вопроса не понятно что делать  с товарами с ценой 0.. в моем примере при значении 0 переходит к следующему элементу - если не подходит вместо `continue` ставишь скобки и запоминаешь товары куда нужно или меняешь значения