# Как не выводить цифру 0 из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста как не выводить цифру 0 рядом со словами 0Даром и 0Обмен

```html
<?php
            
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM              table_products",$connect);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                do{
                    
                    if  ($row["imagesad"] != "" && file_exists("ph_main/".$row["imagesad"]))
                    {
                        $img_path = 'ph_main/'.$row["imagesad"];
                        $max_width = 114; 
                        $max_height = 114; 
                        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
                        $ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
                        $ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
                        $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 
                        $width = intval($ratio*$width); 
                        $height = intval($ratio*$height);    
                    }else
                    {
                        $img_path = "images/no-image.png";
                        $width = 110;
                        $height = 200;
                    }
                    
                                     echo '
                        <li>
                        <div class="block-images-grid">
                        <img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">
                        </div>
                        <p class="style-title-grid"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></p>
                        <ul class="reviews-and-counts-grid">
                        <li><img src="images/eye-icon.png"><p>0</p></li>
                        <li><img src="images/comment-icon.png"><p>0</p></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="style-price-grid"><strong>'.$row["targeting"].''.$row["darom"].''.$row["obmen"].'</strong></p>
                        <div class="mini-features">
                        <p>Город:</p>
                        <p>Дата:</p>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    ';
                }
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
            }
            ?>
```

[image: вот как выглядит конечный результат]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
.$row["targeting"].''.$row["darom"].''.$row["obmen"].
```

на

```
.(!empty($row["darom"]) ? $row["darom"] : (!empty($row["obmen"]) ? $row["obmen"] : $row["targeting"])).
```

P.S. Но лучше программиста нормального наймите...

Comment: Спасибо большое, денег нет на программиста, нанял бы:)